# What is the type annotation for return value of __getitem__?

Tags: python, pytorch, type-hinting

I was making a dataset class by inheriting `torch.utils.data.Dataset` and came across the following issue.

Unlike previous functions which returns a fixed type of values, `__getitem__` doesn't.
For example,

```
class MyExample:
    def __init__(self, some_list: list[int]):
        self.some_list = some_list

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.some_list[index]
```

`MyExample[<index>]` will return `int`, while `MyExample[<slice>]` will return `slice of int`. VScode intellisense automatically write `T_co` for its type annotation, but I don't understand what this means.

- How should I annotate such a function?
- What do I need to learn in order to understand such an annotation?

Comment: BTW, it seems like you only need to specify `__getitem__` for `index` for `torch.utils.data.Dataset`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this you can use Unions as the actual annotation of the function and overload to allow you type checker to know that a slice is only returned when a slice is given and an int is given when only an int is given.

```py
from typing import overload, Union

class MyExample:
    def __init__(self, some_list: list[int]):
        self.some_list = some_list

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> int: ...

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, index: slice) -> list[int]: ...

    def __getitem__(self, index: Union[slice, int]) -> Union[list[int], int]: # Or Slice[int] if that's a thing
        return self.some_list[index]
```

If your example is not only for list of ints but for general lists, you can change to Generic types.

- For details check out [overload document](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#function-method-overloading).
- `...` is actual code.

Comment: In Python 3.10 one can write `slice | int` and `list[int] | int` instead of `Union[slice, int]` and `Union[list[int], int]`.

Comment: I know. Wanted to be not overly cutting edge :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) to describe the  possibility of multiple different return types.

```py
from typing import Union

class MyExample():
    def __init__(self, some_list: list[int]):
        self.some_list = some_list

    def __getitem__(self, index: Union[int, slice]) -> Union[int, list[int]]:
        return self.some_list[index]

a = MyExample([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(a[2])
print(a[1:3])
```

`mypy` reports no issues with the above code snippet.